# How output jade pretty print in sails?

Tags: pug, sails.js

I try to output pretty print from jade in sails. I tried to configure jade like this:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
    // Development environment
    if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {

        sails.config.express.customMiddleware = function () {
            var app = sails.express.app;
            app.set('view options', { pretty:true });
            // app.locals.pretty = true;
       }
    }
    cb();
};
```

but it fails. Any idea how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  // Development environment
  if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {

      console.log('development --------');
      var app = sails.express.app;
      app.set('view options', { pretty:true });
      app.locals.pretty = true;

  }

  cb();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Sails (I'm using v0.11.0-rc4, the pre-release 0.11 branch), sails.express.app does not work.  After reading up on [Sails' Middleware documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware), I added the following code to local.js and it works as desired.  Keep in mind that other config files that have a http.customMiddleware function will override / be overridden by adding this to local.js.

```
http: {
  customMiddleware: function(app) {
    if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {
      app.set('view options', {pretty: true});
      app.locals.pretty = true;
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note, I also added the 'prettyPrint' function and code below to the config/http.js file as part of the middleware stack.  It seems better suited to local.js (code above) in my opinion.

```
// have JADE output nicely on development
prettyPrint: function (req, res, next) {
  if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {
    req.app.set('view options', {pretty: true});
    req.app.locals.pretty = true;
  }
  return next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
module.exports.express.customMiddleware = function () {


};
```